# Java app not connecting with mysql container using docker-compose

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, docker-compose, hikaricp

I'm making a java app using mysql and when I try to do it manually using only docker, I'm succesful:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/dataBase-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar dataBase.jar
EXPOSE 8089
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "dataBase.jar"]
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=8089
spring.datasource.username=devpath
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb-container:3306/chat_db
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

**Commands**

```sh
docker build -t chat-data-base-image .
docker pull mysql:latest
docker run -p 3306:3306 --name mysqldb-container -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_DATABASE=chat_db -e MYSQL_USER=devpath -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password -d mysql
docker run -d -p 8089:8089 --name chat-data-base-container --link mysqldb-container:mysql chat-data-base-image
```

But when I try to use docker-compose with the following settings

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:

  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=chat_db
      - MYSQL_USER=devpath
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
    container_name: mysqldb-container

  appdb:
    build:
      context: ./dataBase
    image: chat-data-base-image
    ports:
    - "8089:8089"
    container_name: chat-data-base-container
    entrypoint: ["java", "-jar", "dataBase.jar"]
    environment:
      - DBHOST=mysqldb
      - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb-container:3306/chat_db
      - spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      - spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
      - spring.datasource.username=devpath
        spring.datasource.password=password
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    links:
      - "mysqldb:mysql"
      - "mysqldb:mysqldb-container"
```

I get the following error:

```
:: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.5.RELEASE)

2020-03-29 15:26:28.837  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.osilva.dataBase.DataBaseApplication  : Starting DataBaseApplication on 0f5e4aaaa194 with PID 1 (/dataBase.jar started by root in /)
2020-03-29 15:26:28.841  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.osilva.dataBase.DataBaseApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-03-29 15:26:29.334  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-03-29 15:26:29.391  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 49ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-03-29 15:26:29.831  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8089 (http)
2020-03-29 15:26:29.841  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-03-29 15:26:29.841  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31]
2020-03-29 15:26:29.881  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-03-29 15:26:29.881  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1005 ms
2020-03-29 15:26:29.991  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-03-29 15:26:30.040  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
2020-03-29 15:26:30.187  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-03-29 15:26:30.251  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-03-29 15:26:31.325 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:354) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) [HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:554) [HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1202) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1233) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) [spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) [spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) [spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at com.osilva.dataBase.DataBaseApplication.main(DataBaseApplication.java:14) ~[classes!/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[dataBase.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[dataBase.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) ~[dataBase.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) ~[dataBase.jar:na]
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
        ... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
        ... 60 common frames omitted
2020-03-29 15:26:32.789  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
2020-03-29 15:26:32.789 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2020-03-29 15:26:32.792  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
2020-03-29 15:26:32.793  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-03-29 15:26:32.801  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-03-29 15:26:32.803 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

I've been searching for days what is wrong with or missing in my docker-compose configuration, but I'm having a really hard time figuring out.

Answer (score 0):

The error points out there is a network issue (Connection refused)

The network/connetion between the two containers seems okay - I tested that locally
`appdb` can reach the other container via `mysqldb` and `mysqldb-container`

Are you sure your app is really using the Environment variable `spring.datasource.url` from the docker-compose.yml? Maybe this configuration is not used at all?

Comment: I'm afraid it's ignoring that field, I'm following this guide https://medium.com/@tariqul.islam.rony/spring-boot-and-multi-stage-dockerized-image-with-mysql-in-docker-compose-part-3-2999b2bdf6aa to try to fix my issue, but open for suggestions to make it work. Also I figured out that this field spring.datasource.url when using docker is jdbc:<database>://<container>:3306/<table> and for docker compose is jdbc:<database>://<service>:3306/<table> . So that's one thing that is wrong . I mean in application.properties file